# How do I populate a ListView with an existing list of arrays to fill both items and sub items?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a linked list of arrays containing exactly two integers each.

I want to populate a ListView with each main item as the 0th integer in the array and its respective sub item as the 1st integer.

I know how to populate a ListView with a list of just integers, but I don't know how to correctly add in the sub items like I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Do you want a nested Listview?

Comment: I've been able to write one for simpler lists. My main issue is that I don't know how to change it to fill in the sub items.

Comment: @praveenSharma, I don't need anything nested, just something like this-- http://i.imgur.com/QUS7tpc.png

So the sub items basically serve as captions.

Comment: @Chase ok so for this use my answer.

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a ListView, with a CustomAdapter, and on the getView of the customAdapter, you have to do something like this:

```
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.list_musics);
list.removeAllViews();

for (Music music : albums.get(position).musics) {
    View line = li.inflate(R.layout.inside_row, null);

    /* nested list's stuff */

    list.addView(line);
}
```